# Is camera application supported by blackberry 10 working with Blackberry Webworks?

Tags: html, camera, blackberry-10

I want to implement camera in my application with HTML5 for blackberry 10 and in search of that I found this page https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.media.camera.html#.takePicture .And after reading that I concluded that camera application is not supported by Blackberry 10 with HTML5.
Am I right??
Please suggest!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact invoke a [camera card](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_2/camera.html), which will slide open a native card to take a picture or video. It will return the file system path in a callback when the card is closed.

If you want to capture media directly within your app, take a look at getUserMedia and the canvas. Here's a good article on it:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

I hope this helps.

John